# Header Footer Format and formula

Tags: vba, excel, header, format

I would like to take a cell reference to another worksheet and put that in the center header and format it to a specific font and size.
Next, I'd like to take the Right header and have either the name of my report as the top, with a bold font of specific size while the line below has a separate size and is not bold.  Like below:

**Compliance Report**  (This doesn't need to be cell referenced, it can stay the same).

Policy Date 2014 | 9/30/15 (This changes from account to account and need to come from a source range.)

I started with this code:

```
Sub header()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup
        .RightHeader = Worksheets("Compliance Report").Range("a99") _
            & Chr(10) & Worksheets("Compliance Report").Range("a100")
        End With
End Sub
```

It works for getting the data on two lines, but I can't format it.  I'm not tied to sticking with this formula if there is a better option.

Comment: A good technique to do this kind of formatting stuff, is to record a macro and do the formatting that you need and then look at the code and modify it however you want.

Comment: So, use my code above to get the info in the header and then record the macro to format it?

Comment: That would work.  I would run your code above to put the data in the right place.  Then I would record a macro and put the formatting I want.  Then, check the code and add it to your existing code once you take out the .selects in the macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
Sub RHeader()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1").PageSetup
       .RightHeader = "&""Courier New,Bold""&12&KFF0000" _
       & Worksheets("Compliance Report").Range("a99") & Chr(10) _
       & "&""Courier New,Regular""&10&K000000" _
       & Worksheets("Compliance Report").Range("a100")
    End With
End Sub
```

`10` and `12` are the font sizes, `KFF0000` is red, hopefully the rest self-explanatory and adjustable.

Comment: Worked Great,  Just what I was looking for.  Thanks so much!