# Formatting the texts using PageSetup.CenterHeader

Tags: vba, excel, footer

I have a form that asks for 1 string for filename and 1 long for a number to use in CenterHeader.

I've got it to correctly perform the above tasks. However, I am looking to further edit/format the text in CenterHeader (Bold, fonts, etc...). I can't seem to figure out how to properly reference it

```
Private Sub Export_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Shelter Run").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Worksheets(1)
    sht.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "Shelter Run#" & TextBox1.Value
    'sht.PageSetup.CenterHeader.Address.Bold = True
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\random\dir" & TextBox2.Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox TextBox2.Value & ".xlsx has been created!"
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried macro recorder?

Comment: Yea, just gives me selection.font.bold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Excel you need to use "escape codes" to add formatting to the HeaderFooter. I've copied an MSDN reference at the end of this Answer with all the currently valid codes.

In order to make the content bold then not-bold, for example:

```
With ActiveWorkbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = .Worksheets(1)
    sht.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&BShelter Run#" & TextBox1.Value & "&B Test"
    .SaveAs Filename:="C:\random\dir" & TextBox2.Value & ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLStrictWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
End With
```

You may also find this [other SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422040/header-footer-format-and-formula) helpful as it contains other types of examples.

***Extract from an [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/formatting-and-vba-codes-for-headers-and-footers)***:

The following special formatting and Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) codes can be included as a part of the header and footer properties (LeftHeader, CenterHeader, RightHeader, LeftFooter, CenterFooter, and RightFooter).

**Format code / Description**

```
&L       Left aligns the characters that follow. 
&C       Centers the characters that follow. 
&R       Right aligns the characters that follow. 
&E       Turns double-underline printing on or off. 
&X       Turns superscript printing on or off. 
&Y       Turns subscript printing on or off. 
&B       Turns bold printing on or off. 
&I       Turns italic printing on or off. 
&U       Turns underline printing on or off. 
&S       Turns strikethrough printing on or off. 
&"fontname" Prints the characters that follow in the specified font. Be sure to include the double quotation marks. 
&nn      Prints the characters that follow in the specified font size. Use a two-digit number to specify a size in points. 
&color   Prints the characters in the specified color. User supplies a hexidecimal color value.
&;"+"    Prints the characters that follow in the Heading font of the current theme. Be sure to include the double quotation marks. 
&;"-"    Prints the characters that follow in the Body font of the current theme. Be sure to include the double quotation marks. 
&;K xx. Syyy Prints the characters that follow in the specified color from the current theme. xx is a two-digit number from 1 to 12 that specifies the theme color to use. *Snnn* specifies the shade (tint) of that theme color. Specify S as + to produce a lighter shade; specify S as - to produce a darker shade. nnn is a three-digit whole number that specifies a percentage from 0 to 100.  
         If the values that specify the theme color or shade are not within the described limits, Excel will use the nearest valid value.
```

**VBA code / Description**

```
&D     Prints the current date. 
&T     Prints the current time. 
&F     Prints the name of the document. 
&A     Prints the name of the workbook tab. 
&P     Prints the page number. 
&P+number Prints the page number plus the specified number. 
&P-number Prints the page number minus the specified number. 
&&     Prints a single ampersand. 
&N     Prints the total number of pages in the document.  
&Z     Prints the file path. 
&G     Inserts an image.
```